# TextBox lose text when I hide it with jquery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, textbox, show-hide

I am using Jquery to hide a textbox and show it when the user clicks a button

Hide:

```
$('#TextBox1').hide();
```

Show:

```
$('#TextBox1').show();
```

Everything works fine. But on google chrome, the textbox is losing its value. if the user type a text then hide it and show it again the textbox is empty.

This is happening only on google chrome. On firefox and explorer it works fine

Any idea about it?

Thanks

EDIT:
There is something i forgot to mention is that i am hiding the DIV that contains the textbox and not the textbox itself
here is the Jcode

```
    $("#EditName").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#TextBoxDIV").show();
    }
    $("#HideName").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#TextBoxDIV").hide();
    }
```

and the textbox

```
    <div id = "TextBox1" class="TextFieldEditSmaller">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name) //This is an MVC3 application
    </div>
```

EDIT2: I just noticed that the text is there but it is hidden behind something. if I CTRL + A inside the textbox and then I copy/Paste in notepad it shows

Comment: Can you post more of your code. The value shouldn't dissappear.

Comment: Do you have a specific test case for it?  Some extra HTML code or JavaScript code to go with this?

Comment: Your "textbox" is a div?

Comment: well the div is called textbox1 but it contains a textbox. I am hiding/ showing the div but the text box in it is losing its value

Comment: Google and MS act funny when placed together :) Why `event.preventDefault();` are you preventing event bubble ? why so ? It means you have more (functionality) attached to it  somewhere

Comment: Yes that was it `event.preventDefault();` was causing the problem. add it as a answer so I accept it

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly for me.

This is the code I use:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>test</textarea>
<button>Hide</button><button>Show</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("button:first").on("click", function(json) {
    $("textarea").hide();
})
$("button").eq(1).on("click", function(json) {
    $("textarea").show();
})
</script>
```

Maybe you post your full code so we can determine what your problem is?

Answer (score 0):

without seeing your actual html code its hard to tell, but what you could do is try to hide the actual textbox then the div, by doing something like:

```
$("#HideName").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#TextBoxDIV").children(":first-child").hide();
    $("#TextBoxDIV").hide();
}
```

and if that doesnt work, you can store the text using jquerys data utility 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

and then re-populate the textbox on show.
access and set the text contents of an html element by using 
http://api.jquery.com/text/
a note: the reason I used the .children(":first-child") is because your mvc3 application is going to be translated into html, and we do not know what exactly its id/class (if any) is going to be